# tilestache url format

Tags: python, tiles, tilestache, slippy

Documentation at http://tilestache.org/doc/#over-http says this is the format of requesting your tile `/{layer name}/{zoom}/{column}/{row}.{extension}`

Now, my question is what column and row stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column and row along with the zoom level are needed to identify a specific tile.

[This](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Derivation_of_tile_names) section in the osm wiki shows how they are calculated.